# Wordpress displays posts of category ID

Tags: wordpress, parent, categories, posts

Can't seem to find the right answer for what I thought would be trivial.

I have some categories arranged like this...

Parent Category 1
  - Child Category 1
  - Child Category 2
  - Child Category 3

...and I have some posts that are in Child Category 2. I want my page to display all posts from the category I am currently in.

This is what I am doing right now:

```
<?php
query_posts('cat=2&showposts=10');
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>      
    <div class="timeline">
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <?php the_content();?>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <?php _e('No Posts Sorry.'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

As you can see I am having to manually specify the category (cat=2), but instead I want it to automatically detect the category I am already in and display the posts (that way if I'm in a different category it will display those posts).

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance. (SO Community = Awesome Sauce).

Answer (score 11):

try below code:

```
<?php
$current_cat_id  = get_query_var('cat');
$showposts = 10;
$args = array('cat' => $current_cat_id, 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'DESC', 'posts_per_page' => $showposts,'post_status' => 'publish');
query_posts($args);
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>      
    <div class="timeline">
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <?php the_content();?>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <?php _e('No Posts Sorry.'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you have an error in that:  

**'posts_per_page'=> $showposts _no,**  

should be this just be...  

**'posts_per_page'=> $showposts,**  

Anyhoo, that shows all posts instead of just the ones for that category :-(

Also if I throw a **echo $current_cat_id;** in the loop it doesn't display the category ID as expected, so I can only assume it's not actually getting it.

Comment: Thanks sandip. You saved my time.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `category.php`, you can omit the `query_posts` and it will auto fill in the posts for you.

Comment: Why aren't you using it? You say you want to "display all posts from the category I am currently in". Best practice when trying to achieve this is tu use the `category.php` (and child files), as described in Codex.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
    // Start the loop.
    $categories = get_categories('child_of=1');//Parents category id
                        foreach ($categories as $cat) {

                            $option = '<a href="/category/archives/'.$cat->category_nicename.'">';
                            $option .= $cat->cat_name;//parents sub category name
                            $option .= '</a>';
                            echo $option;
                            query_posts('cat=$cat->cat_ID&showposts=10');
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>      

<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<?php the_content();?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<?php _e('No Posts Sorry.'); ?>
<?php endif;  }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
<?php
global $post;

$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'offset'=> 0, 'category' => 1 );
// 1 is a cat id.
// 

$myposts = get_posts( $args );

foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
<li>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'offset'=> 0, 'cat' => 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this is better solution for this and you can also use it to show Related Post by a category id...

Just call the function that mentioned below by using this line. Put this in your template or page.php/single.php file.

Call by put this line: `related_post_title('enter cat id here..');`

Here is the Function and put this in `function.php` file.

Related posts function:

```
function related_post_title($cat_id){

    $cat = $cat_id;

    // Check if it is page only
    if ( is_page() || is_single()) {
        $args=array(
            'cat'  =>  $cat,
            'order'  =>  DESC,
            'orderby'  =>  rand,
            'post__not_in'  =>  array($post->ID),
            'posts_per_page'  =>  9999,
            'caller_get_posts'  =>  1
            );

        $my_query = null;

        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

            echo  ' <ul> ';

            while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

            <?php

            endwhile;

            echo '</ul>';
        }
        wp_reset_query();
    }
}
```

If any query please let me know, i will help you...